# How I can make like a soft end that hides my letter?

Tags: css

[image: My Form]

How I can make like a soft end that hides my letter (The "D" it's like truncated; i want it like with a gradient)

Thx :D

**EDIT:**

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="GET" class="buscar_form">
    <input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar_form_input_text">
</form>
```

Comment: Where's your html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.test {
  background-color: rgb(102, 51, 153);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}



.test:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(102, 51, 153) 20px, rgba(102, 51, 153, 0));
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'> lorem ipsum </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that i'm working with a input and i can't click like "to edit" because there's a background